Resolving Dependency Issues in MSIX Packaging of Console and WINUI3 Applications
I am encountering challenges with the MSIX packaging process for integrating a console application within a WINUI3 project, both intended to be included in the same MSIX package. To achieve this, I have configured a post-build command for the console app, which relocates all binary files to the WINUI3 application's directory, allowing both to be packaged together.
Here is a snippet of the console application's project file for reference:
<Project.LegacyPipelineServer>
    <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
        <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
        <Platforms>AnyCPU;x64</Platforms>
        <FileVersion>$(internalVersionNumber)</FileVersion>
        <AssemblyVersion>$(internalVersionNumber)</AssemblyVersion>
        <CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <ProjectReference Include="..\..\Project.Calculation\Project.Calculation.csproj">
            <Private>True</Private>
        </ProjectReference>
        <ProjectReference Include="..\DLLBridge\DLLBridgeLibrary.csproj">
            <Private>True</Private>
        </ProjectReference>
    </ItemGroup>
    <Target Name="PostBuild" AfterTargets="PostBuildEvent">
        <Exec Command="xcopy /E /Y &quot;$(TargetDir)*.*&quot; &quot;..\..\Project\LegacyDLLServer\&quot;" />
    </Target>
</Project.LegacyPipelineServer>

While this setup successfully includes the executable, I am facing issues with unresolved dependencies during runtime when using the MSIX package. Specifically, the dependencies of referenced projects such as "Project.Data" are not found, despite the existence of the respective DLL in the same directory as the console app. This leads to the following error:

Exception: Could not load file or assembly 'Project.Data, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.

Interestingly, this setup functions perfectly within Visual Studio, but encounters issues only in the MSIX package. I have attempted adding local copies without success. Any guidance on resolving these dependency resolution issues in the MSIX package would be highly appreciated.
